# Line (39) IndexError: pop index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, popup

This is my code:

```
#cart is a list, easy to append
cart=['S/n'," "*10, 'Items', " " * 14, "Quantity", " " * 8, "Unit Price", " " * 8, "Price"]
total_pricee = 0
pricee = 0
count=1
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print( "Date & Time:",dt_string)
print('Welcome to tis program.Please use the numbers to navigate!')
def invalid_input(Quantitiy):
    while Quantitiy > '5' or Quantitiy < '1':
        Quantitiy = input("Please key in a valid quantity(Between 1 to 5):")
        if Quantitiy < '5' and Quantitiy > '1':
            New_Quan=Quantitiy

            #This part of function checks if item quantity is between 1 and 5
            return Quantitiy

            break
    while not Quantitiy.isdigit():
        Quantitiy = input('Invalid input.Please enter a valid input:')
        while Quantitiy.isdecimal() == False:
            break
    #This part of function checks that item quantity is not a decimal
    return Quantitiy

def add_to_cart(name, Quantity, price):
    global total_pricee, pricee,count,cart

    #This function adds items to cart
    cart.append('\n')
    cart.append('{:<10s}'.format(str(count) + '.'))
    cart.append('{:^10s}'.format(name))
    cart.append('{:^30s}'.format(str(Quantity)))

    cart.append('$'+str(price)+'0')

    pricee = '{:.2f}'.format(float(Quantity) * price)
    pricee

    cart.append('{:^34s}'.format('$' +str(pricee)))
    total_pricee += float(pricee)
    count = count +1
    print(name,"has been added to cart!")
def remove_from_cart(Item_number):
    global count
    while True:
        if Item_number>(count-1):
            print('Please key in a valid S/n!')
            (Item_number)=int(input('Please enter the S/n of the item you want to remove:'))
        if Item_number==2:
            cart.pop(9)
            cart.pop(9)
            cart.pop(9)
            cart.pop(9)
            cart.pop(9)
            cart.pop(9)
        if Item_number<=(count-1):
            x=(6*(Item_number-2))+9
            cart.pop(x)
            cart.pop(x)
            cart.pop(x)
            cart.pop(x)
            cart.pop(x)
            cart.pop(x)
            print('Item has been sucsussfully removed from cart!')
        if count==1:
            print('Please add an item to cart first!')
while True:
    print('[1] Water')
    print('[2] rice')
    print('[3] ice')
    print('[0] View Cart and Check-out')
    print("[4] Remove object from cart")
    opt = input("Select option:")
    if opt > '4' or opt < '0':
        print("Select valid option!")
    if opt == '3':
        qunt = input("Please key in a quanity for your item:")


        qunt =invalid_input(qunt)
        nam3 = "Ice"
        add_to_cart(nam3, qunt, 2.00)
    if opt == '1':
        qunt2 = input("Please key in a quanity for your item:")

        qunt2=invalid_input(qunt2)
        nam2 = "  Water"
        add_to_cart(nam2, qunt2, 3.00)
    if opt == '2':
        qunt1 = input("Please key in a quanity for your item:")


        qunt1=invalid_input(qunt1)
        nam1 = "Rice"
        add_to_cart(nam1, qunt1, 5.00)
    if opt == "0":

        print(*cart)
        print("Total price until now:", "$" + '{:.2f}'.format(total_pricee))
        print('Would you like to check out?')
        print('[1] Yes')
        print('[2] No')
        checkout=input("Please select an option:")
        if checkout=='1':
            print('You have bought',count,'items')
            print("Please pay""$" + '{:.2f}'.format(total_pricee))
            print('Thank you for shopping with us!')
            exit()
    if opt=="4":
        print(*cart)
        remove=input("Please key in the S/n of the item you want to remove:")
        remove_from_cart(int(remove))
        print(*cart)
```

I do not know why this error is occurring .I am a bit new to python and have not encounter such error before.Please tell me how to improve my code such that this error does not occur again. Thanks to anyone who helps!
For eg:

```
S/n            Items                Quantity          Unit Price          Price 
 1.            Rice                   3                $5.00               $15.00               
 2.            Rice                   4                $5.00               $20.00               
 3.            Water                 4                $3.00               $12.00
```

and user wants to remove the second item, it the output after the function has been carried out should be

```
S/n            Items                Quantity          Unit Price          Price 
 1.            Rice                   3                $5.00               $15.00                              
 2.            Water                 4                $3.00               $12.00
```

Comment: L.pop([index]) -> item -- remove and return item at index (default last). Raises IndexError if list is empty or index is out of range.  Your problem description x > len(cart)-1

Comment: so i should just  remove it?

Comment: First you have to explain what your code is for. Describe the problem clearly so that you can answer it better.

Comment: Alright.So basically, I am creating a code that is kind of like a shopping cart.So I have a function for adding to cart,however, I need to create a function that gives the user the option to remove item in cart.

Comment: You need to judge x <= (len(cart)-1) before pop, moreover, just pop once. Do not use `while True`, as this will cause an endless loop unless you have an exit condition

Comment: I have updated the question so you have a clearer understanding

Comment: Just read your update, you can use `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: My cart is a list, so im a bit unsure about that...I have updated with the actual code that I created so farr...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help!However I have encountered another issue, when user opts to remove item from cart, the total price does not change...You can see it more better here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62399575/total-price-does-not-change-when-i-remove-item-from-the-cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't paste the formatted code in the comment, I will write it in the answer, I hope to understand.
The list is very inconvenient to do this operation

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [5]: d = pd.DataFrame([['Rice', 3, '$5.0', '$15.0'], ['Water', 4, '$3.0', '$12.0']], columns=['Items', 'Quantity', 'Unit Price', 'Price'])

In [6]: d                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[6]: 
   Items  Quantity Unit Price  Price
0   Rice         3       $5.0  $15.0
1  Water         4       $3.0  $12.0

In [7]: d.drop(0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[7]: 
   Items  Quantity Unit Price  Price
1  Water         4       $3.0  $12.0

In [16]: d.append([{"Items": "Rice", "Quantity": 3, "Unit Price": "$5.0", "Price": "$20.0"}], ignore_index=True)                                                                                                                              
Out[16]: 
   Items  Quantity Unit Price  Price
0   Rice         3       $5.0  $15.0
1  Water         4       $3.0  $12.0
2   Rice         3       $5.0  $20.0
```

Comment: but the thing is, in my program, I do not store the items in the cart...so i dont think data frame is possible

Comment: `d` can be added dynamically, and does not need to be stored. When not needed, you can directly `d = None`

Comment: I somewhat understand

Comment: You can also use `dict`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code, maybe for your reference :)

```
from itertools import repeat

class Cart():

    def __init__(self):
        self.header = ['S/N', 'Items', 'Quantity', 'Unit Price', 'Price']
        (self.SN_width, self.item_width, self.quantity_width,
            self.unit_price_width, self.price_width
            ) = self.widths =[13, 19, 16, 18, 20]
        self.item_list = {}

    def get_serial_no(self):
        i = 1
        while i in self.item_list:
            i += 1
        return i

    def add(self, item, quantity, unit_price):
        serial_no = self.get_serial_no()
        self.item_list[serial_no] = (item, quantity, unit_price)

    def delete(self, serial_no):
        del self.item_list[serial_no]
        lst = sorted(self.item_list.keys())
        new_list = {i+1:self.item_list[key] for i, key in enumerate(lst)}
        self.item_list = new_list

    def sum_all(self):
        all_price = 0
        for item, quantity, unit_price in self.item_list.values():
            all_price += quantity*unit_price
        return all_price

    def adjust(self, items):
        line = ['']*5
        for i in range(5):
            if i == 0:
                line[0] = items[0].center(self.widths[0])
            elif i == 1:
                line[1] = items[1].ljust(self.widths[1])
            else:
                line[i] = items[i].rjust(self.widths[i])
        return ' '.join(line)

    def __repr__(self):
        keys = sorted(self.item_list.keys())
        title = self.adjust(self.header)
        seperator = ' '.join(list(map(str.__mul__, repeat('-'), self.widths)))
        result = [title, seperator]
        for key in keys:
            lst = self.item_list[key]
            items = [str(key), lst[0], '%.3f'%lst[1], '$%.3f'%lst[2],
                     '$%.3f'%(lst[1]*lst[2])]
            line = self.adjust(items)
            result.append(line)
        return '\n'.join((' ', '\n'.join(result), ' ',
            'Total price: $%.3f'%self.sum_all(), ' '))

cart = Cart()

new_items = [
    ('apple', 10, 1), ('orange', 5, 0.5), ('banana', 20, 0.2),
    ('avocado', 5, 0.2), ('cherry', 1, 20), ('grape', 1, 15), ('lemon', 5, 1)]

for item in new_items:
    cart.add(*item)

while True:
    print(cart)
    try:
        action = input('Add(A), Delete(D), Exit(E) :').strip().lower()
    except:
        continue
    if action == 'a':
        try:
            item = input('Name of item: ').strip()
            quantity = float(input('Quantiy: ').strip())
            unit_price = float(input('Unit Price: ').strip())
        except:
            print('Wrong data for item !')
            continue
        cart.add(item, quantity, unit_price)
    elif action == 'd':
        key = input('Serial No. to be deleted: ').strip()
        try:
            key = int(key)
            if key in cart.item_list:
                cart.delete(int(key))
                continue
        except:
            pass
        print('Wrong serial No. !')
    elif action == 'e':
        break
    else:
        print('Wrong action !')

print('Bye !')

``
```